# Bash aliases - how do I run a file in a different folder without losing my current location?

Tags: bash, scripts, bashrc, alias

I have a nice little bash alias in my .bashrc folder that allows me to start Tomcat running without having to cd into the folder first, e.g.

```
alias startTomcat="cd ~/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/ && ./startup.sh"
```

However when I run `startTomcat`in a terminal, I'm booted out of the folder I started in, and now my terminal's residing in `~/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/`. This is expected behaviour, of course, but what I'd like to do is run the command without winding up in a different folder.

Can I either **save the original location, then return to it** in my .bashrc file, or alternatively **run startup.sh without `cd`ing out of the original folder**?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the absolute path for `startup.sh` without to `cd` in the folder where is located::

```
alias startTomcat="~/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/startup.sh"
```

Or, you can use `cd -` which will return you to the directory where you were last time:

```
alias startTomcat="cd ~/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/ && ./startup.sh && cd -"
```

Comment: Doh! I'd tried *nearly* that, but I assumed I'd have to add . to the front, and thus, it didn't run. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Radu's answer is good, but depending on use case you may want to use `pushd` and `popd`, which lets you save and restore directories. Something like:
`alias startTomcat="pushd ~/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin; ./startup.sh; popd"`